# how can I make android dialog not swallow touches

Tags: android, popupwindow

How can I make android dialog not swallow touches. And pass the touches to the parent window?

Please point me to any examples if possible.

do you know how I can dispatch the event to the window?
I tried to make a custom dialog and override dispatchTouchEvent

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
        PGLog.log(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent %s", super);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: can you just make the dialog swallow it and do the "things" that the parent would do after swallowing it..?

Comment: no I need a better solution. As the dialog is used at a lot of places

Comment: What do you mean with parent view? A dialog is part of a window, do you mean that window or do you mean views in another window (like the Activity's window)? If it's the latter why would you want that? Dialogs in Android are modal so the user should not be able to interact with another window while the dialog has focus.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin do you have any suggestion for me?